# How do I calculate a P-Value from 2 custom data sets?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

I have 2 custom data sets:

```
data1 = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/KHkmEfQB", "List"];
data2 = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/Hm3mhczi", "List"];
```

These are available here:

[data1_pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KHkmEfQB)
[data2_pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Hm3mhczi)

(I actually import these from files but you get the idea).

The data sets are NOT normally distributed.  Here's an image of `data1` and `data2`, respectively:

[image: data1]
[image: data2]

I create a distribution from both:

```
skdData1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data1, Automatic, {"Bounded", {20, 105}, "Gaussian"}];

skdData2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data2, Automatic, {"Bounded", {20, 105}, "Gaussian"}];
```

Now, I would like to test `data2`'s $p$-Value for `data1`'s distribution.  I am going to be manipulating `data2` in a variety of ways, and want to keep testing the $p$-Value to see which manipulation makes the best fit.  I won't go into the details of that here, but I need a way to accurately compare `data2` to `data1` and the only built-in function I found in *Mathematica* are for normal distributions.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please consider posting (a subset of) your data to [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com/) so that other people have something to work on.

Comment: data subsets added!

Comment: So, you want to do something like `DistributionFitTest[data2, skdData1, {"TestDataTable", All}]`?

Comment: Well, my concern with that is that I this gives me a P-Value less than 1:
`DistributionFitTest[data1, skdData1, "TestDataTable"]`
It's close to 0.84, which is weird to me... since I made the distribution from that data set...

Comment: Think of what a [P-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value#Definition_and_interpretation) means and you will come up with the conclusion that p=1 would be quite fishy.

Comment: Contrast `DistributionFitTest[data1, skdData1, "TestDataTable"]` with 
`DistributionFitTest[data1, 
 EmpiricalDistribution[data1], "TestDataTable"]`

Comment: That you will be manipulating `data2` sounds fishy.  Do you mean you will be manipulating the parameters in the process that produces data sets like `data2`?  It's your odd use of statistical terms such as "my concern with that is that...this give me a P-Value less than 1" - all P-values range from 0 to 1 and P-values from samples from the tested distribution will essentially never be 1.  They will have a uniform distribution - U(0,1).  And "I would like to test `data2`'s p-Value for `data1's distribution".  P-values aren't tested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149794/fitting-data-to-an-empirical-distribution-finding-best-fit where two samples are being tested for arising from a common distribution.